# Show $f_t- a x f_x + \frac{1}{2} b \sigma^2 f_{xx}=0$ has solutions of the form $f(x,t) = C(t) e^{-D(t)x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

> Show 
>   $$\partial_t f(x,t) - a x \partial_x f(x,t) + \frac{1}{2} b \partial_x^2 f(x,t)=0$$
>   has solutions of the form 
>   $$f(x,t) = C(t) e^{-D(t)x^2}$$
>   and find the differential equations satisfied by $C(t)$ and $D(t)$.

I'm lost on how to begin here. I have not taken a course in PDE's but I would like to know how the above is solved on my way to a larger result in probability.

Is there a "standard" method for such a problem? I've looked at the "ansatz" method which involves taking a guess of the form we wish to show, but I don't see how that would lead to a proof of forms for the solution.

Comment: Apparently, you are expected to plug in the given formula into the PDE and check that it satisfied it.

Comment: Forgot to add the last part of my quote, which is why I had the differential-equation tag on.

Comment: Okay, you are still supposed to plug $f$ in, and see what the thing simplifies to. The result will be a differential equation for $C$ and $D$.